# Soft keyboard not hiding

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm invoking a mail app to send mails on behalf of my application, using the code below:

```
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("plain/text");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {
        address
    });
```

After clicking on the send button, the control will be returned to my application. 
Now the problem is while editing the mail - the soft keyboard will pop up. Even after returning to my application the soft keyboard won't be hidden. How can I hide this keyboard in my application?

I tried the code below but it's not working.

```
   final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mUsernameEdit.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: Issue solved. i used view.getApplicationWindowToken() instead of view.getWindowToken(). it's working fine. Thanku for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use onFocusChangeListener on EditText and add the following in its overriding method

```
if(!hasFocus) {
<your edittext instance variable>.setFocusable(false);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

// Add this to ur activity in Android Manifest file  will solve ur problem,

```
<activity android:name=".ur activity name" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
```